# Convergence of the sequence $z_1=\frac{3}{2}$ with $z_{n+1}=\sqrt{3z_n-2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Prove the convergence of the sequence $(z_n)$ such that :
$$ z_1=\frac{3}{2}$$ $$z_{n}=\sqrt{3z_{n-1}-2}$$ for every $ n \geq 2$.

Calculate also the limit.

I have applied induction: $$\frac{3}{2} \le z_n \le 2 \ \ \ \ \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$$

The sequence is strictly increasing and it's also bounded so it converges .

$$ L=\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n=2$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, but to be completely legit (or even just pass the test of "proof-checking"), you should  add the following details:

- *boundedness*: give the details of the induction, if you want us to check it;
- *monotonicity*: the sequence is indeed increasing, but how did you show it? (e.g., "the function $x\mapsto\sqrt{3x-2}-x$ is positive on $[3/2,2)$")
- *limit*: the only two possible limits are indeed $2$ and $1$ (fixed points of the function $x\mapsto \sqrt{3x-2}$). But you should state how you got this $2$ (basically, what I have just written, and why only $\ell=2$ is possible, not $\ell=1$).